# multisite same language different translation

Tags: translation

I am ruing multisite, and I have two sites, and the two sites are sharing two plugins, pro and free; I have translated the two plugins on the first site.

And I want to edit a few strings on the second site; when I do that, the string change on the first site and vice versa.

How can I have two translation files with the same language, and each site has its own translation file?

the bottom line: i want to make each site has it own translation not sharing the same translation.

i am using Loco Translate

Answer (score 0):

If this is just your own personal project with plugins you developed and they plugin won't be more widely distributed, you could just put subdirectories inside the `languages` directory that correspond to the site ID and load them conditionally:

```
function myplugin_load_textdomain() {

    $current_site_id = get_current_blog_id();
    
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' . $current_site_id . '/' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );
```

So `/languages/1` would be for the main site, and `/languages/2` would be for the subsite.

If the plugin will be distributed, you could perhaps add however many sets of translations you want and then add a plugin settings page where the user/you can choose which translation the site uses from a drop-down.

Or, if these are not your own plugins, [then this may help you.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101975/can-a-plugin-be-run-in-a-different-language-than-wordpress)